# How do you redirect a bare "example.com" domain to "https://example.com"?

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https, ssl-certificate

Title really says it all. I cannot get my domain to redirect from `site.com` to `http://example.com` but `https://example.com` works as well as `https://www.example.com`.

My nginx conf is as follows with sensitive paths removed. Here is a GIST link to all my nginx setup, it is currently the only enabled domain in my entire [nginx configuration](https://gist.github.com/rublev/c75cc58a5ca051ddafa99c00673ea911).

Console output on my local vs my server:

```
rublev@rublevs-MacBook-Pro ~
• curl -I rublev.io
^C
rublev@rublevs-MacBook-Pro ~
• ssh r
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-75-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

78 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Fri May 12 16:41:35 2017 from 198.84.225.249
rublev@ubuntu-512mb-tor1-01:~$ curl -I rublev.io
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 12 May 2017 16:41:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 339
Last-Modified: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 20:47:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "58f91e50-153"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I am at my wits end, I truly have no idea what to do now, I've spent weeks trying to get this working.

Comment: Use rewrite rules, from the looks of it, you're trying to set up something with let's encrypt too... see https://serverfault.com/questions/768509/lets-encrypt-with-an-nginx-reverse-proxy

Comment: @photoionized I'm running a bunch of simple sites from different directories all on port 80, all on different domains. no need for a reverse proxy. Or maybe I need a reverse proxy? I have no idea.

Comment: Config looks ok, so on risk of sounding odd: Can you confirm `rublev.io` is resolving as intended on all participating machines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LetsEncrypt is using http by default, just to be safe, it's preferable to leave the ability for it to access the `well-known` for the acme challenge. You also don't seem to be pointing to the right path for it, unless you changed your webroot to `/home/rublev/sites/rublev.io`?

I would try to rewrite your default server like this instead of redirecting directly to your `https` equivalent. Besides, it will allow you to test more easily this strange behavior.

```nginx
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name rublev.io www.rublev.io;

  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    # Apparently you changed your webroot,
    # just make sure that the file is created and accessible
    root /home/rublev/sites/rublev.io/.well-known;
  }
}
```

Also, it's very important to know that you need either two different certificates or one that accept your domain both with and without `www` form. If that was not the case, that might very well be the reason of your issue. To generate a cert with both domains, you can run the following command:

```
sudo ./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d rublev.io -d www.rublev.io --dry-run
```

I would also comment out your jenkins server and configs, just in case it's messing with your main one. Note: from [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/372889/276120), you can use `proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;` instead of the form you're currently doing. It shouldn't affect another server, but I prefer to be sure in these weird scenarios.

---

Another thing, that might be the path to another solution, would be to consider picking only one form of your domain (either with or without `www`), and redirecting users from the "wrong" to the "right" one. This will allow you to get more consistent urls, better for SEO and people sharing your links.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. Thank you! Enjoy the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the server

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```